# Webassembly from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I have a C ++ program with 1000+ lines (using vector and stdlib.h). The program consists of one function that takes five unsigned int (or 1 unsigned char and 4 unsigned int) as an input, returning a string or 4 unsigned int (I do not understand how to return an array of numbers, so I use a string).
I compiled the program using WasmExplorer into a .wasm file.

How to call the function from .wasm file from javascript, getting the result?
I have tried:

```js
let squarer;

function loadWebAssembly (fileName) {
  return fetch (fileName)
    .then (response => response.arrayBuffer ())
    .then (bits => WebAssembly.compile (bits))
    .then (module => {return new WebAssembly.Instance (module)});
};
  
loadWebAssembly ('http://test.ru/squarer.wasm')
  .then (instance => {
    squarer = instance.exports._Z7squareri;
    console.log ('Finished compiling! Ready when you are ...');
  });
```

Error in Chrome (I have 29Kb .wasm file)

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: WebAssembly.Instance is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.instantiate.
```

How to call a function from JS (with an example)?

Specific function in wasm/wasm-000197c6/wasm-000197c6-22 in Chrome

Comment: Can you share the C++ code, or at least the wasm binary?

Comment: Why is it needed? The code compiles fine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is clearly stated in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem and the solution is clearly stated in the error message: you should use the `WebAssembly.instantiate()` function instead of the `WebAssembly.Instance()` constructor.